# What rules govern the parent-child relationship of processes launched by shell across a pipe?

Tags: shell, process, pipe, ksh, fork

```
#!/bin/ksh
# start_service: start the service
my_server_executable 2>&1 | my_pipe_following_shell_script &
exit 0
```

After I run the above `start_service` script from command line, it is observed using `ps` command that the `bash` process running `my_pipe_following_shell_script` is parent of `my_server_executable`, whereas I would expect, *and need*, the latter to be owned by PID 1 (`init`) instead.

**I am looking for an explanation as to why this has happened and how I can avoid this**.

Also how does one go about debugging/examining what goes on behind-the-scenes? Running `start_service` with `strace` isn't very helpful. The only interesting line I could find in its output is:

`clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7f05708) = 30431`

where `30431` is PID of `my_pipe_following_shell_script`.

---

Linux 2.6.18-308.16.1.el5PAE

ksh Version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-02-02

GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1):

Your shell — `ksh` in this case — is the parent of the processes on *both* sides of the pipe, because it started them both. All it does between starting one and the other is set up the pipe between them, so that the [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdout#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) of the first goes to the [stdin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdout#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) of the second.

If you need the two-process agglomeration to be run in the background, this will do it:

```
( my_server_executable 2>&1 | my_pipe_following_shell_script ) &
```

That starts the two programs — connected via a pipe — within a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html), which is put into the background via `&`.